# ImageAnnotatorClient google vision API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vision-api

Trying to use node to run a label detection with the vision api:

```
'use strict';
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

// Creates a client
const client = new ImageAnnotatorClient({
projectId: 'my-project-xxx',
 keyFilename: 'Users/xxx/Downloads/xxx.json',
});

// Performs label detection on the image file
client
 .labelDetection('.//Users/xxx/Downloads/menu.jpg')
 .then(results => {
   const labels = results[0].labelAnnotations;

console.log('Labels:');
labels.forEach(label => console.log(label.description));
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error('ERROR:', err);
 });
```

Continuously receiving error: "ImageAnnotatorClient is not defined"
Any reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try modifying the line:

```
const client = new ImageAnnotatorClient({
```

for:

```
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient({
```

The ImageAnnotatorClient method is extracted from the Cloud Vision API, which you imported as the `vision` variable.

Comment: I tried this, but this error is returned: "TypeError: vision.ImageAnnotatorClient is not a constructor"

Comment: Which version of the library are you running? ( `npm ls @google-cloud/vision` )

Comment: Upgrade the package to the latest version (0.14.0): `npm install --save @google-cloud/vision`